# Tooltip on the screen

Tags: android

I want to implement tooltips to be shown near some `Views` in my application. How is it possible to show some views over existing `layout`? How to position it where I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [`PopupWindow`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), you can show it at any position with it's `showAtLocation()` method.